# Update a SQL column if value is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a bit value (in Status) i want to display its status in gridview as if true, the row display "Active", otherwise the row display "Inactive", this is my code, but the result displays True or false itself. And based on the `Active` or `Inactive`, the Action column must display `Deactivate` or `Activate`

```
ShopNumber  ShopName    Address Website   Status    Action  Settings
2             abc        Kuwait xyz.com     True    Deactivate  Edit
3             def        Kuwait deuuy       False   Activate    Edit
4            Major       Minor  Usra.com    True    Activate    Edit
5             Isys       Kuwait isys.com    False   Activate    Edit
6            Avenues     Kuwait avenues.com False   Activate    Edit
```

Here is the codebehind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            Boolean bitCheck = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
            if (bitCheck)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Active";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Inactive";
            }

        }
```

Here is ASP code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
         AllowSorting="True" 
         onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
         DataKeyNames="TempID">

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShopNumber" HeaderText="ShopNumber" SortExpression="ShopNumber" >
            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShopName" HeaderText="ShopName" SortExpression="ShopName" >
            <ItemStyle Width="170px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" >
            <ItemStyle Width="170px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Website" HeaderText="Website" SortExpression="Website" >
            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="Action">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textAction" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Action") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Action") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Settings" ShowEditButton="True" >
            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:CommandField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you binded this cell in grid markup ?

Comment: show your aspx code of relevant column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using item template, not just binding it to the column. So you'll have to cast the `Label` to edit it's `Text`.

```
Label status = (Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label2");
Label action = (Label)e.Row.Cells[5].FindControl("Label1");

Boolean bitCheck = Convert.ToBoolean(status.Text);
if (bitCheck)
{
    status.Text = "Active";
    action.Text = "Activated";
}
else
{
    status.Text = "Inactive";
    action.Text = "Deactivated";
}
```

Comment: what if I use remove the item template and use BoundField like other columns? What changes do I have to make to the above code to make it  work?

`<asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" 
                    SortExpression="Action" />`

Comment: Your code will work fine in that case. As you were accessing `e.Row.Cells[4]` directly.

Comment: I tried your solution but the values in `Status` column remains `True` or `False`.

Here is the table:

`ShopNumber int 
ShopName nvarchar(50) 
Address nvarchar(50)
Website nvarchar(50)
Status bit
Action nchar(10)
TempID int `

Could you have a look once more.

Comment: I tried both ways using the respective codebehind but no luck

Comment: Thanks got it working

Missed: `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` in my `GridView` control